# How to open .aspx webpage,fill form and submit

Tags: python, selenium, mechanize, python-webbrowser

**Requirement**:
I need to open a webpage thats on my company server, fill the aspx form (dropdown menus) and submit it.
I can open the page in internet explorer without any issue.
While trying to open it using any other browsers, it asks for credentials like:

"""The server http://someserver:80 requires a username and password."""

I can enter my credentials and then the page will open.
I need to automate this in Python and share the final product.

**What i have tried**:

1. Selenium : It requires webdrivers to be downloaded and thus i wont be able to share the end product
2. Mechanize: Not able to authenticate by adding the headers:

`br.addheaders.append(('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user,pass))))`

3. successfully opened webpage using webbrowser module. But unable to fill the dropdowns.

Can anyone suggest me how i can pass my credentials along with the request.
Or if someone can tell me how i can call the webpage and fill form and submit, would be really helpful.

Comment: Could you give a screenshot of the username and password that it asks for?

Comment: @selten98 I am not able to attach image here in the question. So here is a link to the image: http://s33.postimg.org/j0hdo1vtb/auth.png

Comment: You can open such a webpage by doing: http://user:password@someserver:80/ in your HTTP request. That way you can access the webpage.

Comment: @selten98 This is the webpage i am trying. : http://myapps/register/aspx/attendance/form.aspx. Could you please elaborate your answer based on this. Can i give the request like http://user:password@http://myapps/register/aspx/attendance/form.aspx ?

Comment: You're forgetting the someserver:80 it seems

Comment: @selten98 that worked. http://user:pass@someserver/myapps/register/aspx/attendance/form.aspx. Now i can try filling the form and submitting using mechanize. Thank you.

Comment: @selten98 Can you tell me what kind of authentication this is?

Comment: Regular HTTP authentication, it does the same as when you fill it in when accessing the site